# SQL Group By string concatenation by comma and period

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I've 3 tables, namely Customer, Application, Agent. The structure and sample data for the 3 tables are as follows

```
Customer
==========
PKCustomerID    | CustomerName
1             | Test Customer1
2             | Test Customer 2

Application
============
PKApplicationID | ApplicationTitle | FKCustomerID 
1 | TestApplication1 | 1 
2 | TestApplication2 | 1 
3 | Test Application3 | 1

Agent
======
PKAgentID | AgentName | FKApplicationID | ComparableCode<br>
1 | AgentName 1 | 1 | AgentCode1
2 | AgentName 2 | 1 | AgentCode1 
3 | AgentName 3 | 2 | AgentCode2
```

Now I need a resultset which is like for a given CustomerID

```
ComparableCode |  ApplicationNamer.AgentName | ApplicationCount 
AgentCode1 | TestApplication1.AgentName1,TestApplication1.AgentName2 | 2
```

I've written the following code

```
SELECT ComparableCode, AgentName = 
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + AgentName
       FROM LNAgent b 
       WHERE b.ComparableCode = a.ComparableCode 
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''), COUNT(PKAgentID) [Application Count]
FROM LNAgent a
JOIN LNApplication app
ON app.PKApplicationID = a.FKApplicationID
JOIN LNCustomer cust on
cust.PKCustomerID = app.fkCustomerID
GROUP BY ComparableCode
ORDER BY [Application Count] DESC
```

The above query giving me the following result set

```
ComparableCode | ApplicationNamer.AgentName | AplicationCount
AgentCode1 | AgentName1, AgentName 2 | 2
```

I'm unable to include the ApplicationName in the ApplicationName.AgentName column.

Please, help

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirement correctly then you need to include LNApplication inside the FOR XML sub-select;

```
SELECT ComparableCode, AgentName = 
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + app2.ApplicationTitle + '.' + a2.AgentName
       FROM LNAgent a2 
       JOIN LNApplication app2
       ON app2.PKApplicationID = a2.FKApplicationID
       WHERE a2.ComparableCode = a.ComparableCode 
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''), COUNT(PKAgentID) [Application Count]
FROM LNAgent a
JOIN LNApplication app
ON app.PKApplicationID = a.FKApplicationID
JOIN LNCustomer cust on
cust.PKCustomerID = app.fkCustomerID
GROUP BY ComparableCode
ORDER BY [Application Count] DESC
```